# BeautifulSoup - Blank line in the output 'cause a strange useless <tr></tr>

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

Little problem for you :-)

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse the content of a table in a HTML page. The problem is that between every line (CSV/EXCEL) of my output file, it pulls a blank line... 
This is an exemple of the HTML Table (which is very big)

```
<tr><td class="normaltext" valign="TOP">Tesco - United Kingdom&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td class="normaltext"  valign="TOP">CO</td>
<td class="normaltext"  valign="TOP">Unknown&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td class="normaltext"  align="center" valign="top">lol</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5"><hr></td></tr>
<tr><td class="normaltext" valign="TOP">Tesco - United Kingdom&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td class="normaltext"  valign="TOP">CO</td>
<td class="normaltext"  valign="TOP">Unknown&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td class="normaltext"  align="center" valign="top">lol</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5"><hr></td></tr>
```

Every < tr> you have this : **< tr>< td colspan="5">< hr>< /td>< /tr>** So It put a blank line in my CSV/Excel Sheet. I want to pull in the Excel Sheet all the information but without a blank line between every line ...

Here is the script I use :

```
rows = tableau[3].findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td', attrs={'class' : 'normaltext'})
    y = 0
    x = x + 1
    for td in cols:
        texte_bu = td.text
        texte_bu = texte_bu.encode('utf-8')
        texte_bu = texte_bu.strip()
        ws.write(x,y,td.text)
        y = y + 1
```

BIG THANKS to the one who can give me the tip to get rib of this *** blank useless line between every line of my output file :)

Comment: What is `ws`? That seems to be where the issue is. The string `<tr><td colspan="5"><hr></td></tr>` won't match when you include `attrs={'class' : 'normaltext'}`.

Comment: ws.write come with wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8') and is linked to xlwt which is a module that allows me to write directly into excel sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution: when you find an empty row, then skip the loop and read in the next row. This avoids your writing an empty line to the workbook. :)

This is a working simulation. I have added a cosmetic adjustment in order to also avoid the top empty row being sent out. Hope this rids you of empty-line peskiness :)

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import xlwt

text = '''<table><tr><td class="normaltext" valign="TOP">Tesco - United Kingdom&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td class="normaltext"  valign="TOP">CO</td>
<td class="normaltext"  valign="TOP">Unknown&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td class="normaltext"  align="center" valign="top">BULATS</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5"><hr></td></tr>
<tr><td class="normaltext" valign="TOP">Tesco - United Kingdom&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td class="normaltext"  valign="TOP">CO</td>
<td class="normaltext"  valign="TOP">Unknown&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td class="normaltext"  align="center" valign="top">BULATS</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5"><hr></td></tr><table>'''

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('a test sheet')

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.findAll('tr')
x = 0
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td', attrs={'class' : 'normaltext'})
    if not cols: 
        # when we hit an empty row, we should not print anything to the workbook
        continue
    y = 0
    for td in cols:
        texte_bu = td.text
        texte_bu = texte_bu.encode('utf-8')
        texte_bu = texte_bu.strip()
        ws.write(x, y, td.text)
        print(x, y, td.text)
        y = y + 1
    # update the row pointer AFTER a row has been printed
    # this avoids the blank row at the top of your table
    x = x + 1

wb.save('example.xls')
```

Comment: Guy, that works fine ! Thank you very much for your help. That was kind of a "logic" solution ! Thanks !